# Why Kafka/Flume integration is needed for spark streaming? Can't spark streaming consume data directly from the sources?

Tags: apache-spark

Can someone give a use case where we should use the Spark Streaming directly and where we should go for integration with Kafka/Flume ?

Comment: Kafka and flume are just popular streaming backends. There's also an API to implement a consumer for your source. What do you want to consume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a use case where we should use the Spark Streaming directly

There's an API that you can use to write your receiver or consumer and Kafka is among the sources Spark Streaming supports out of the box. Kafka is also an external storage so asking about "using Spark Streaming directly" is a sort of misnomer as a Spark Streaming application has to read datasets from *somewhere*.

> where we should go for integration with Kafka/Flume?

IoT devices are sending tons of data every minute (or seconds to make things worse) and Kafka acts as a **shock absorber** so Spark can process the datasets on its pace.

Spark Streaming (and Structured Streaming) are batch-oriented and pull-based so the data has to be available to be fetched and processed. Kafka (or Cassandra) are often used to take the load and keep the data before Spark is read to handle it. They just make Spark Streaming's life so much easier and peaceful.

> Can't spark streaming consume data directly from the sources?

A Spark Streaming application does consume data directly...always. The point is what is the meaning of "directly" in your question. Is Kafka not "directly from the sources"? Kafka may be (and often is) the source.

If however you mean "beside Kafka", the answer is yes. Kafka is among the sources Spark Streaming pulls data from.

Quoting Spark Streaming's [Input DStreams and Receivers](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers):

> Spark Streaming provides two categories of built-in streaming sources.
>
> **Basic sources**: Sources directly available in the StreamingContext API. Examples: file systems, and socket connections.
>
> **Advanced sources**: Sources like Kafka, Flume, Kinesis, etc. are available through extra utility classes. These require linking against extra dependencies as discussed in the linking section.

And later in [Custom Sources](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#custom-sources):

> Input DStreams can also be created out of custom data sources. All you have to do is implement a user-defined receiver (see next section to understand what that is) that can receive data from the custom sources and push it into Spark. See the Custom Receiver Guide for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacek. You gave me a clear picture on why exactly Kafka is required.